# How to use answer of NDSolve in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

```
a = 3; Tau = 100; T0 = 1/2; g0 = Tanh[2/T0];
z0 = (1 - g0) Tau;
s = NDSolve[{D[G[q, x], x] + (2 z0 (1 - x)^a + q^2) G[q, x] == 
Sqrt[2/Pi] q, G[0, x] == 0, G[10, x] == 0.0795932, G[q, 0] == 0.797885 q/(q^2 + 2 z0)}, G[q, x], {q, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 20]
 Plot[(G[q, x]) /. s /. q -> 0.5, {x, 0, 1}]
P[y_, x_] := Sqrt[2/Pi] NIntegrate[Sin[q y]*G[q, x], {q, 0, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 20]
```

Here, I want to use the G[q,x] from the NDSolve, as solution in the NIntegrate code of P[y,x]. But I am not able to understand how to call it. This code is working till Plot of G[q,x]. But P[y,x] is giving a lot of errors.

Comment: For example, use `G` in `NDSolve`.  `a = 3; Tau = 100; T0 = 1/2; g0 = Tanh[2/T0];
z0 = (1 - g0) Tau;
sol = NDSolve[{D[G[q, x], x] + (2 z0 (1 - x)^a + q^2) G[q, x] == 
    Sqrt[2/Pi] q, G[0, x] == 0, G[10, x] == 0.0795932, 
   G[q, 0] == 0.797885 q/(q^2 + 2 z0)}, G, {q, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 20]; 
P[y_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[2/Pi] NIntegrate[Sin[q y]*G[q, x] /. sol[[1]], {q, 0, 10}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 20]; P[3, 2]`

Comment: It works, thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and see if this works for you.

Btw, you are also getting

```
 NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
```

which you might want to fix.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 3; Tau = 100; T0 = 1/2; g0 = Tanh[2/T0];
z0 = (1 - g0) Tau;
solG = NDSolveValue[{D[G[q, x], x] + (2 z0 (1 - x)^a + q^2) G[q, x] == 
    Sqrt[2/Pi] q, G[0, x] == 0, G[10, x] == 0.0795932, 
   G[q, 0] == 0.797885 q/(q^2 + 2 z0)}, G, {q, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 20]

Plot[solG[0.5, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
P[y_, x_] := Sqrt[2/Pi] NIntegrate[Sin[q y]*solG[q, x], {q, 0, 10},AccuracyGoal -> 20]
```

and now

```
 P[1, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[P[2, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also think it will be better/safer to define your `P` as

```
P[y_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ]
```

Since `y,x` could only be numerical for things to work, because you are using `NIntegrate`.